# While logged-in to WordPress.com, leaving a comment in a blog adds "www" to my own blog's link?

Tags: wordpress.com

While logged to my WordPress.com account, I left a comment on another blog (specifically, [a post on TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2010/08/15/venture-capital-super-angel-war-entrepreneur/)). My blog's domain is [roadler.com](http://roadler.com), however the comment was left with the URL [www.roadler.com](http://www.roadler.com). It does redirect properly, but still a bit annoying. I could not find a setting that fixes it nor did I find anything on WordPress.com or Google. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but maybe the folks at wordpress.stackexchange.com will.

Answer (score 2):

When adding your web address to any online form, type in the full address, i.e.

```
http://roadler.com/
```

This will prevent "helpful" server side validation from adding assumed canonical information to the address.